# How to double buffering a WebKit page using QWebView and PySide?

Tags: python, qt4, webkit, pyqt, pyside

I am playing with PySide and QWebView to provide a WebKit version of a webapp on Windows.

Simple and easy to install in a complex working Windows environment where only Internet Explorer exists.

More over using QWebKit it is quite simple :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

#       hellowebkit.py


#       Copyright 2009 Piotr Maliński, riklaunim@gmail.com
#       
#       <Under GPL licence>

import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://myapp.example.com"))
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would like to enable double buffering so that there is no drawing until the next page is fully loaded.

Do you know how I should do that?
I guess maybe using `web.loadFinished()` signal?

Cheers,

Natim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `QStackedWidget` and a `QSignalMapper` to do that:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Create a stack with 2 webviews
stack = QStackedWidget()
mapper = QSignalMapper(stack)
mapper.mapped[int].connect(stack.setCurrentIndex)
for i in range(2):
    web = QWebView(stack)
    stack.addWidget(web)
    # When a webview finishes loading, switch to it
    web.loadFinished[bool].connect(mapper.map)
    mapper.setMapping(web, i)

# load the page in the non visible webview
stack.widget(1).load(QUrl("http://myapp.example.com"))
stack.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```